# How to merge test report of elixir umbrella app?

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

We have an elixir umbrella app with 2 child apps.
Currently we get 2 test reports as there are 2 child apps.
Is there a way to merge the results into one?

Current report:

```
Finished in 1.4 seconds
5 tests, 0 failures, 1 excluded
Finished in 0.5 seconds
2 tests, 0 failures
```

Expected report:

```
Finished in 1.9 seconds
7 tests, 0 failures, 1 excluded
```

Comment: That is normal, These are seperate elixir applications. So, it is expected to have standalone tests. Why do you want to merge?

Comment: @HaseebEqx I understand that these are standalone tests. No issues with that.
Actually my problem is that the my tests are quite verbose and I have to scroll a lot to see if any of the tests of the 1st app has failed.
I just expect to see the cumulative results at the end of the test to avoid this.
Currently I am using this https://github.com/navinpeiris/ex_unit_notifier for a better experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built-in way to merge results from different umbrella applications into one report. However you can write custom reporter that will output results of all tests into shared file(s) and then display report using such file. Alternatively you can use some kind of pipeline tool that would gather tests results and then result with one, joined result. You could look for example for TAP output format for that.